# prove that $|\aleph_{\beta}+\aleph_{\beta}|=\aleph_{\beta}$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Assume that I have already proved for $ \beta\in On$ that $ |\aleph_{\beta}\times\aleph_{\beta}|=\aleph_{\beta}$.
Is it correct to conclude that:

$$ |\aleph_{\beta}+\aleph_{\beta}|=|\aleph_{\beta}\times2|\leq|\aleph_{\beta}\times\aleph_{\beta}|=\aleph_{\beta} \ \text{?} $$

Also, if the answer for the first question was yes, is it correct to conclude that if $A, B$ are two sets such that $ |A|\leq\aleph_{\beta}$ and $|B|\leq\aleph_{\beta} $, then

$$ |A\cup B|\leq |A\ \dot{\cup}\ B| \leq|\aleph_{\beta}+\aleph_{\beta}| \ \text{?} $$
(Here, $\dot{\cup}$  is disjoint union.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes and yes, respectively!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both are correct.

One thing to notice, though, is that $\aleph_\beta$ is *already a cardinal*, and $+$ between two cardinals is always assumed to be *cardinal addition*. Therefore the correct notation is $\aleph_\beta+\aleph_\beta$, rather than $|\aleph_\beta+\aleph_\beta|$. Similarly for $\times$.

You can also prove this directly by noting that $\omega_\beta$, the initial ordinal of size $\aleph_\beta$ satisfy that $\{\alpha+1\mid\alpha<\omega_\beta\}$ and $\{\alpha+\omega\mid\alpha<\omega_\beta\}$ are disjoint and both have cardinality $\aleph_\beta$, which gives us a quick and direct proof of the fact about addition.

Comment: I thought that cardinal is an ordinal itself, so why would'nt it satisfy : $ |\aleph_{\beta}+\aleph_{\beta}|=otp\left\langle \aleph_{\beta}\uplus\aleph_{\beta},<\right\rangle  $ ?  Also why is it correct notation to write $ \alpha<\omega_{\beta} $ I mean, those are ordinals, wouldnt it be more precise to write $ \alpha\in\omega_{\beta} $ ?

Comment: Yes, cardinals are ordinals. But there is a reason why we use $\aleph_0$ and also $\omega$. It's not because we want to be redundant. It's because the notation sets up the context, is this ordinal arithmetic or cardinal arithmetic? As for the order on the ordinals, we *define* $\alpha<\beta$ if $\alpha\in\beta$, and again the choice of notation is meant to set up context: ordinals are not just von Neumann ordinals, they are order types.

Comment: I see. Its a bit confusing to me, because we defined in class for two sets $A,B$ $ A\leq B $ if there is an injective function from $ A $ to $ B $. Assume $ |A|=\alpha $ and $|B|=\beta$ , would it be wrong to note $ \alpha\underline{\in}\beta $ in order to say that the cardinal of A is less then B or equal to B ?

Comment: You should never, ever, ever never, write $\underline{\in}$. :-)