# Prove that $ \kappa\times\lambda=\lambda $

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

let $  \kappa<\lambda  $  and assume $ \aleph_{0}\leq\lambda $

prove that: $ \kappa\times\lambda=\lambda $

So, my attempt, based on the fact that i already proved for infinite cardinals $ \lambda $ that it follows : $ \lambda\times\lambda=\lambda $

if $ \kappa\neq0 $
choose $ \kappa,\lambda $ to be ordinals  (we can choose because the definition cardinal arithmetic is well defined)

then $ \kappa\times\lambda\subseteq\lambda\times\lambda=\lambda $

and therefore $ \lambda\leq\kappa\times\lambda\leq\lambda $

and from Cantor-Bernstein theorem, it follows that $ \kappa\times\lambda=\lambda $

But im not sure what about the case $ \kappa =0$   is the statement holds? I mean what happens when we multiply the cardinal zero with infinity?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is this different from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3725451/prove-that-aleph-beta-aleph-beta-aleph-beta?

Comment: Cantor-Bernstein is also called Schroeder-Bernstein and Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein. I was once puzzled  when one book referred to C-B, which I didn't know was the S-B of  another book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the case $\kappa = 0$ requires special attention. In that case we are looking at $0 \times \lambda$, which is just the cardinality of $\emptyset \times \lambda = \emptyset$. So $0 \times \lambda = 0$.

In particular, the inequality $\lambda \leq \kappa \times \lambda$ will not hold if $\kappa = 0$. But for any other $\kappa$ it will hold and your proof is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If $\kappa=0$ then $\kappa\times \lambda$ is the cardinality of $A\times B$, where $\lvert A\rvert=0$ and $\lvert B\rvert=\lambda$. Therefore $A=\emptyset$, and $A\times B=\emptyset$.

Therefore the claim should include the hypothesis $\kappa\ge1$.